# Ionic custom directive is Ignored by Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, directive

I created a custom directive in ionic

```
ionic g directive directives/time-value
```

My code is

```
import { Directive, OnInit, Input, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appTimeValue]',
})
export class TimeValueDirective implements OnInit{

    @Input('appTimeValue') myStyles: any;

    constructor() { 
      console.log("I'm here");
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
      console.log("I'm here");
  
    }
}
```

then I tried to use the directive

```
<ion-input type="text" name="fineColazione" [(ngModel)]="fineColazione" appTimeValue></ion-input>
```

Ionic is ignoring my directive.

the CLI added the directive in the module declaration

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TimeValueDirective,
  ],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule, 
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

How can I make the directive work?

Comment: are you using TimeValueDirective directly inside of the template of AppComponent ? if not - directive should be imported in the Shared module - module which is imported everywhere

Comment: CLI added the directive in the main module app.module.ts . I assume is avaliable to all madules.

Comment: no, it doesn't work like that in angular. all declarations are shared only in the module. also  the ones in `exports` section are shared when you are importing the shared module into one of your modules

Comment: In my project I have  AppModule and then 2 more modules  SettingsPageModule and HomePageModule that are lazy loaded but I can't find a SharedModule in the project structure generated by CLI. If I include the directive into the SettingsPageModule nothing changes.

Comment: if this directive is used inside of SettingsPageModule components, then import it there. also use it like `[appTimeValue]`. you will see not found error in this case, rather just not working directive

Comment: Thanks now it works I removed the directive from the mainModule and put it in the SettingsPageModule. If you post the answer I'll uprate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TimeValueDirective should be declared in the same module, as the one that contains the component, which uses that directive. also it is a good practice to make SharedModule with all reusable components/directives/pipes inside of the application and import this module everywhere.